# MipMapLinearLinear in Libgdx-Android

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying to set the filter for the texture to have smooth image. It is working good for Linear or nearest. But when I tried MipMap I am getting the black screen only. Could you please let me know how to use the MipMap in Libgdx.

```
BACKGROUND           = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/gamescreen.png")); 
BACKGROUND.setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear, TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use [special Texture constructor](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html#Texture-com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle-boolean-) if you want to use mipmap filtering.

Second, you can't use `TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear` for magnification filter. It just don't make sense.

So, in your case the code should be:

```
BACKGROUND = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/gamescreen.png"), true); 
BACKGROUND.setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

Comment: using this code code i could see some of my devices have the irregular images on it. Is it a side effect f mipmap ?

Comment: What do you mean by irregular images? Could it be that your texture is non-power-of-two texture? If so can you test the code with some power-of-two texture?

Comment: Irregular in the sence i could see black patches in between the images. Even when the images size is made as power of 2, I am scared to use MipMapLinearLinear instead of Linear. 
Will there be any great difference in MipMapLinearLinear Vs Linear

Comment: I don't think you'll see great difference. Can you please post a screenshot with such black patches? By the way is your texture a separate image or sprite atlas?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have user linear itself, Because I have the image of size not in power of 2.